# Why parameter of contains() of list class differ from containAll()?

Tags: java, collections

Hi I checked Params of Contains methods and ContainsAll method .

```
boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c);

boolean contains(Object o);
```

It seems both will accept Object . Is there any difference among two.

Comment: Did you read the javadoc?

Comment: I don't see what's unclear here? contains checks for one Object, and containsAll checks for one or more Objects.

Comment: Yeah .. both nothing fruitfull

Comment: They don't both accept `Object`. The first one only accepts a `Collection`.

Comment: _Returns true if this collection contains the specified element._ and _Returns true if this collection contains all of the elements in the specified collection._ I don't see how that can be any clearer.

Comment: See Sytnax they could have written  boolean containsAll(Collection<Object> c) instead of boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c);

Comment: You cannot cast Collection<YourType> to Collection<Object>

Comment: If you pass a collection to both of them then `contains` will check if the actual collection is present, while `containsAll` will check if the elements within the collection are present.

Comment: If you have a completely different question, ask it in a new question.

Comment: Collection<?> is not the same as Collection<Object>. If it had been Collection<Object> the method would not have accepted a Collection<String>. Google generics and covariance.

Comment: Your real question: *what's the difference between `Collection<?>` and `Collection<Object>`* is answered here: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1065197)

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not both accept Object. Let us assume you have an Collection x:

The first method (`x.containsAll(c)`) accepts a `Collection c` and will return true if ALL elements in that Collection are also contained in x.

The second one (`x.contains(o)`) accepts an `Object o` and will return true if that Object is contained in x.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between contains and containsAll is that contains check if 1 Object (the parameter) exists in the list while containsAll check if the list contains ALL the elements in the given collection (hence the all in the method's name).

Also containsAll may accept Object because Object is the superclass of every class in Java. However, if the Object you pass is not an instance of Collection, you'll have a ClassCastException at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference. `containsAll` will not accept Object. It will only accept a Collections of Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Method below accepts any type since all derive from `Object`

```
contains(Object o);
```

Method below accepts a collection of any type since wildcard `?` is used:

```
containsAll(Collection<?> c);
```

Comment: read the comment on the second method, I mean that first accepts any type and the second accepts a collection of any type

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - updated so it reads more clear, still a downvote?

Comment: I just removed the bad wording of the post.

Comment: well, that was a crucial part of my answer since I wanted to stress that they have some 'synergy'

Comment: And that's wrong. They don't have some synergy. They're different methods.